# How to make fixed horizontal menu as image below on top of page

Tags: css

I need to make a horizontal menu on top of the page like the image bellow :

[image]

I tried to make it in fiddle, but the problem is it does not display

```css
.ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0;
  /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">الرئيسيه</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#news">نبذه عن</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contact">اتصل بنا</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**So that how to make fixed horizontal menu on top of page as image above ?**

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmedsa/7x76kj57/) is the link to the fiddle

Comment: `ul` isn't a class. it's element. remove dot here: `.ul {...`, thus it should work  https://jsfiddle.net/banzay52/sd3tayo5/

Comment: thank you can you tell me how to put red line above to my menu

Answer (score 0):

ul isn't a class. it's element. remove dot here: .ul {..., thus it should work.

to make top red line along menu you cal jusr set `border-top: 4px solid red;`

```css
ul {
    border-top: 4px solid red;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">الرئيسيه</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">نبذه عن</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">اتصل بنا</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: only if possible if i need to add | between every word how to add

Comment: I need to add | between every words in menu

Comment: your question was: "So that how to make fixed horizontal menu on top of page as image above ?".

Comment: style border-right or border-left for li. I think It's better to create a new question for this.